# Add Reference to a WCF Service Executable

Tags: .net, wcf, service, reference

I have 3 projects in my solution. 1 - client, 2 - server, 3 - WCF service library.
Server executable exposes the service provided in the library. I need to add a reference to it, rather than to the library directly. When I open "Add Service Reference" and click "Discover", it only lists the library data, and doesn't list the executable server option.

How do I reference a WCF executable service, so the client code would be generated automatically?

I use VS 2010.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just found this:  
"When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When deploying the service library
>   project, the content of the config
>   file must be added to the host's
>   app.config file. System.Configuration
>   does not support config files for
>   libraries.